I installed Tailwind.css and don't understand why the changes doesn't appear when i try to render my page in react + vite
I've been trying to integrate Tailwind CSS into my React project, but I'm encountering an issue where the changes I make to my components don't appear when I try to render them. Here are the steps I've followed:

Ran pnpm run dev: This command successfully starts the development server and I can access my application at localhost.

Installed Tailwind CSS using the command pnpm install -D tailwindcss.

Added Tailwind CSS to the dependencies in my package.json file:


"dependencies": {
  "tailwindcss": "^3.0.0"
} 


Modify a component of my project in this way :

<button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out" onClick={() => router(`/${text.toLowerCase()}`)}>

But nothing happen.

if you haven't done this yet: Do as it follows:

create the 'tailwind.config.js' in the main folder of your project, with the following content:

tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Change the content property in case your source files are in a different folder.

create an input CSS file in your source folder, like this:

src/input.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


Add a build script to your package.json


"build-css": "tailwindcss build -i ./src/input.css -o
./dist/css/output.css"

Then run the script to compile your output css.
OBS.If your distribution css files are in a different place, change it in this script.

Now load your compiled css in your html.


<link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">

The complete instructions and customizations can be found in tailwind documentation:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
